# How do I use jQuery to get the id of a lookup field when the field is changed?

Tags: lookup, jquery

I am using jQuery to try to get the id of a lookup field (Account_Contact__c) when the user selects a different value.  Here is my code:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();   

function handleResult(result, event) {
    j$('[id$="Account_Contact_Email__c"]').val(result); 
}

j$(document).ready(function(){
    j$(document).on('change', '[id$="Account_Contact__c"]', function() {
        var newAccountContactId = j$('[id$="Account_Contact__c_lkid"]').val();
        console.log(newAccountContactId);  //this is returning an empty string
        myVFPageController.myMethod(newAccountContactId, handleResult);
    });
})
```

The problem I'm facing is that newAccountContactId keeps coming up empty, even when there's a value in there.  However, if I run j$('[id$="Account_Contact__c_lkid"]').val() in the console in Firefox, it returns the correct value.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookup Id is not populated the exact time the value of the lookup is changed. So I suggest you add a small timeout after the change and then check for the value. Try something like this:

```
j$(document).on('change', '[id$="Account_Contact__c"]', function() {
    //add a 200 milisecond timeout
    setTimeout(function(){
        var newAccountContactId = j$('[id$="Account_Contact__c_lkid"]').val();
        console.log(newAccountContactId);  //this is returning an empty string
        myVFPageController.myMethod(newAccountContactId, handleResult);
    },200);
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Brilliant!  Thank you so much!!